# What does the suffix of a temporary table's name mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables, system-databases

If you expand the tempdb node and go to Temporary Tables, you will notice the name of the temporary tables have "***_*__*_*_**_XXXXX" appended. Where does that part refer to?Is it the memory place where the temporary table is created?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporary tables are physical tables as well, just like any other table. They are just a bit special and entail automatic cleanup when they go out of scope. To avoid name clashes, since everyone wants their temporary table to be named `#tmp`, SQL Server generates a pseudo-random name to be given to the physical table that gets created in `tempdb`.  This is associated to your reference to the temporary table, e.g.  `SPID 1234 "#tmp" refers to tempdb.dbo.#tmp___________0000000001CA`.  Note also that even though you can see the table in tempdb.sys.tables from another session, it doesn't mean you can select from it the normal way, e.g.

```
create table #tmp (a int); insert #tmp values (1),(2);
select * from [#tmp_____________0000000001CA]  -- run by creator of #tmp

Results: 

a
-
1
2

select * from [#tmp_____________0000000001CA]  -- run by another session

Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#tmp____________0000000001CA'.
```

There is no inherent meaning to the *XXXXX*.

Comment: Thanks mate! I'll wait for some replies if someone can come up with a meaning to that suffix. Otherwise, will approve correct.

Comment: You already got the answer for 'meaning' - there is no meaning. It's automatically added to avoid name clashes ;)